# Fetching an external page and parsing meta-tags without Regex in C#?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, meta-tags

Consider the following code:

```
public ActionResult Index(String URLQuery = "http://www.google.com")
    {

        HttpWebRequest webRequest;
        HttpWebResponse webResponse;

        int bufCount = 0;
        byte[] byteBuf = new byte[1024];
        String queryContent = "";


        webRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(URLQuery);
        webRequest.Timeout = 10*1000;
        webRequest.KeepAlive = false;
        webRequest.ContentType = "text/html";

        webResponse = (HttpWebResponse) webRequest.GetResponse();

        StreamReader responseStream = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);

        queryContent = responseStream.ReadToEnd();

        ViewData["StreamResult"] = queryContent;            
        return View();
    }
```

Essentially, this simply grabs a web page and spits it out as-is.  What I'd like to do is take the resulting fetched data from the screen, and parse it much like PHP allows you to do using some sort of built-in DOM object/framework.  I have seen many examples of Regex to accomplish this task but I feel like that is inefficient and results in too many weird edge-cases that might result in corrupt data on my end.

Is this even possible?  Am I doomed to use Regex for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a parser for this - it looks like [HTML agility pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) will do what you want.

Comment: I was hoping that there might be some unknown class or feature built-in to .Net to assist me, but this looks promising.  Thank you, will try now.

Answer (score 1):

Using [HtmlAgility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) you can do this very easily. Below a sample using XPath, the newer version does support Linq syntax as well, but I haven't tried that yet personally.

```
    StreamReader responseStream = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream(), 
                                                   System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);

        queryContent = responseStream.ReadToEnd();
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(queryContent);
        HtmlNode bodyNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body | //BODY");
        /* do processing here */
```